# Want to split a string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, openpyxl

Im using discord.py to make discord bot for a game called rocket league. In rocket league you can trade items and my trading discord is used for such stuff. So i decided i wanted to be able to log all trades, the person who listed the trades discord id, and the platform which they play rocket league on(as there is no cross platform trading).
A trade offer looks like this:

[H] items [W] offer

and i want to split that string so that i can put the [H] and [W] in different columns in a .xlsx file (excel)
if its unclear just ask for clarification about whats unclear.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what [H] and [W] will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
text  = "[H] items [W] offer"
items = text.split("items")[0]
offer = text.split("items")[1].split("offer")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can solve your problem:

```
import re
regex = r"(?P<items>\d+) items (?P<offers>\d+) offer"
test_str = "10 items 30 offer"

variables = re.match(regex, test_str).groupdict()
# {'items': '10', 'offers': '30'}

variables.get('items')
# '10'

variables.get('offers')
# '30'
```